# Captura select como input

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando capturar el `onChange` de un select y que obtengo de la siguiente manera:

```
@if (!Model.Id.Equals(null))
        {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Modificar.IdClase, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase", Model.Modificar.IdClase), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
        }
        else
        {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaClases, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
        }
```

Al realizar una captura del activo con:

```
var clases = $('#Id').val() != "" ? $('#Modificar_IdClase') : $('#ListaClases');
```

Me he dado cuenta que me coje el Modificar como `input` en vez de `select` entonces no me captura el cambio de opción. ¿Qué está ocurriendo y cómo lo soluciono?

Dejo captura del `console.log`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tenía era que tenia el id duplicado y capturaba el primer elemento de los dos que habia, el elemento con el mismo id era:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Modificar.IdClase)
```

Que asp.net transforma a Modificar_IdClase, obteniendo dos elementos con el mismo id, eliminando ese intruso el problema desaparece